# Relationships on the front end side of an Access application disappeared

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-jet-ace

I have quite a large Access application with over 20 tables. Of course, all the relationships between the tables are stored in the back end. Until now, front end relationship viewer was showing all the back end relationships but today I noticed that all the relationships in my front end are gone (but they are OK in the back end). What's weird is that now I can edit the relationships in my front end which I think I could not do before, I always had to go to the back end to edit the database. When I try to create a new query, I must now manually link two tables which share a relationship. It's no big deal. It's just weird because Access was not doing this before and I'm afraid that it's gonna come back and bite me in the ass later... What I could do is manually recreate the relationships in my front end but it seems stupid to me and I'd like to avoid it. I there anything I can do to make the relationships reappear in my front end.

P.S. yesterday I had to delete the links to the tables and relink those same tables from my back end to my front end again. Is it possible that that process caused the front end relationships to disappear?

Comment: Maybe some relationships/tables in the diagram got hidden? Right click > `Show All`.

Comment: No, every relationship is gone. Show all doesn't do anything.

Comment: I would try re-linking the tables. At the end of the day, it really does not matter what the front end shows, since all "control" of relationships etc. ALWAYS is set in the back end anyway.